# Patron en c# dado un metodo o funcion leer de un webservice o servidor base de datos local

Tags: c#, sql-server, webservice, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un programa que dado un mismo metodo devuelve un resultado que puede ser consultado en un webservice o directamente de una base de datos en servidor local.
Creo que esto se puede hacer usando una clase "interface" pero no se si es lo correcto o como deberia implementarlo.

El esquema seria el siguiente:

```
     -----------------------------------------
     Metodo: List<trabajadores>(int idEmpresa)
     -----------------------------------------
           /                            \
     ------------                   ------------
      Web service    <- ----- ->     server sql
     ------------                   ------------
                                         |
                                    ------------
                                     bbdd local
                                    ------------
```

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que pretendes, normalmente un webservice actua como intermediario con la bbdd, ¿Por qué no implementas eso en el  webservice?

Comment: Tengo una aplicacion donde los metodos hacen una consulta a un servidor local con su base de datos. Queria hacer lo mismo con metodos que se llamaran igual pero la conexion la hiciera a un webservice.

Comment: Entonces quieres sustituir las consultas a bbdd por un webservice?

Comment: Si eso es  las consultas de la bbdd por un webservice pero manteniendo tambien las consultas directas al servidor y en caso que mas me interese activar consulta en modo webservice o en modo directo.

Comment: Tal vez [esto](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_web_services.htm) te sea de ayuda para crear el webservice, pero lo de conservar los dos métodos no lo veo necesario

Comment: Gracias y para darle seguridad al webservice? Se puede enviar password y contraseña atraves de https?

Comment: La [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-set-the-security-mode) te muestra un ejemplo,

Comment: Gracias es bastante espeso. Lo que no entiendo es si ya tengo la url como "https" haya que configurar algo en el webservice. Todo lo que va por https ya esta cifrado no se porque hay que configurar el web.config